# python - good way to compare 2 dictionaries with nested values of different types?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I'm new to python and have written some code that does this comparison, but it's really inefficient and like 150 lines long.

Here are 2 example dicts to compare (in reality they are much longer, but are not much deeper than this, and only these data types).

```
dict1 = {
  'id': '1',
  'file': 'filename1',
  'namespace1': {'key1': 'val1',
                 'key2': 'val2',
                 'key3': 'val3'},
  'namespace2': {'key4': ['listval1', 'listval2', 'listval3'],
                 'key5': 'val5'}
}

dict2 = {
  'id': '2',
  'file': 'filename2',
  'namespace1': {'key1': 'val1',
                 'key2': 'val2',
                 'key3': 'val7'},
  'namespace2': {'key4': ['listval1', 'listval2', 'listval7'],
                 'key5': 'val5'},
  'namespace3': 'key6'
}
```

Is there any efficient way to compare these two dictionaries and store the differences to display? I'm having a really hard time with this... I'm thinking the correct way is to convert to sets and recursively compare, but I'm not sure it's going to work properly. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to be more accurate by "compare" definition.
Maybe try to use deepdiff package using:

```
pip install deepdiff
```

Use as follow:

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
print DeepDiff(dict1, dict2)
```

It show exactly what are the changes between those two dicts

Comment: .. if only there was a way to ignore type changes ;(

Comment: ;) i just converted everything to unicode, works great